# Can i approximate a system of two objects attached to a rope with a single object?

Tags: mass

If i have two objects of a generic mass attached to an ideal rope (no mass and no stretching possibility) like this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIVvZ.png can i consider the whole system (object rope object) as one object with the mass equal to the sum of the masses of the object if they move?( no friction applied)

Comment: Yes.  As long as you are looking outside the system of the masses.  The farther you move away from the system that more accurate the approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you can do this depends on what you're trying to calculate.

Suppose the two blocks are resting on a frictionless horizontal surface, and I grab one of them and pull it with a force $F$ parallel to the surface. What is the acceleration of the system? We can ignore the 'structure' of blocks and rope and easily calculate the acceleration to be $F/(m + M)$. But if we want to know the tension in the rope (it won't be $F$) we can't treat the blocks as a composite object. We have to know which block I'm pulling on, because unless the blocks are of equal mass the tension in the rope will depend on which block I'm pulling.

Another thing to consider: If modeling the blocks as a composite object means treating this system as a particle, then the model is ignoring the shape of the system. So any scenario in which the blocks are subjected to a net torque would be outside the scope of what can model can predict.